# removing mentions (discord.js 12.5.3)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need to remove a user mention from message content, but nothing works.
Discord.js version: 12.5.3

```
var content = message.content.toLowerCase().slice(6).trim().replace(/@(everyone)/gi, "@evеryone").replace(/@(here)/gi, "@hеre");
   !message.content.trim().endsWith('-test');

   if (message.mentions.users.size) {
      const mentioned = message.mentions.users.first();
      content.replace(``, '') // here is a problem
      var form = `${content}`;
   } else {
      doSomething()
   }
message.channel.send(form);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its really simple actually. Discord.js has its own function for that: [`Util.cleanContent()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-cleanContent)

You can replace all your code with this one-liner:

```js
message.channel.send(discord.Util.cleanContent(message.content, message))
```

or (as [@MrMythical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15781079/mrmythical) rightfully mentioned):

```js
return message.reply(message.cleanContent)
```

The message still looks the same, just without the pings.

Comment: [`Message.cleanContent`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=cleanContent) will also work

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes("@")) {
message.delete()
message.reply("Do Not Ping!")
}
```